# Convert serialized-hash to Model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delegates

I have a serialized data on my ActiveRecord model, and I want to delegate certain attributes to it. Something like this:

```
class Object < AR::Base
  serialize :data
  delegate :title, to: :data
end
```

But of course this doesn't work for a hash. Is there some other way?

What I want in the end is this. I give the ActiveRecord model a list of symbols:

```
[ :title, :size, :color ]
```

They are transformed into getters and setters like so:

```
def title
  data[:title]
end

def title=(val)
  data[:title]= val
end
```

And they are represented next to the rest of the AR attributes:

```
#<Model id: 21, title: "Foo", size: 4, color: nil>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. First be specific, what you have and where you want to go.which method of Hash you want to delegate to which class?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I've updated my code to give a more specific example..

Comment: But your question subject is confusing. `method delegation` is different thing.Still not I am in right track :(

Comment: Updated the title, I still find it hard to 'speak' code, but I think this is less confusing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`store`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: [ :color, :homepage ]
end

u = User.new(color: 'black', homepage: '37signals.com')
u.color                          # Accessor stored attribute
u.settings[:country] = 'Denmark' # Any attribute, even if not specified with an accessor
```

Comment: That indeed looks just like the thing I need! I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm, now I only need to send this over to my Backbone front-end, but I think I can figure that out.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the general method_missing :

```
def method_missing(m, *args, &block)  
  if delegates.include?(m)
    return data[m]
  end
  super(m, *args, &block)
end
```

[method missing](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_object.html#Object.method_missing) will be called for each method that does not exists on the object, so you can see if the method is one of those you want to delegate.

Comment: This is indeed a solution, but is only a `getter` right? I was hoping for some build-in function actually.. I'm trying with `module_eval` now, which ables me to also generate a `setter`.. But still hoping for something more elegant..

Comment: Which works, but now I only need to get these in line with the other attributes that ActiveRecord adds to the model from the DB scheme..